# Which is the appropriate translation of 'multilingual'?

Tags: translation, word-usage, dictionaries

I want to use the phrase in **a multilingual dictionary**.
There are several options that I have in mind, but I have no idea which one (or none) should I memorise.

> lingva, multa lingva, multlingva, plurlingva

In addition, if I want to say that **some one is multilingual (or n-lingual)** what should I say instead?

Sincere thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oni uzas kaj *plurlingva vortaro* kaj *multlingva vortaro*.

Parolanto de multaj lingvoj estas *plurlingvulo*. Mi ankaŭ vidis *poligloto* aŭ *multlingvano* sed nur unu retejo uzas tiajn vortojn.